# Lambda-Local not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: node.js, npm, aws-lambda, npm-install, package.json

Hi I am working on a lambda function on aws environment(node.js). Whereby to test the function locally, I was using `lambda-local` utility.
Now might be due to version changes, it's throwing error

`lambda-local' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

But I can't figure out how to make it work. I tried downgrading to a previous version of `lambda-local` to no avail. Also there's nothing much over the internet which deals with some kind of issue.

versions:

`npm version : 6.9.0
node version: v10.16.0
lambda-local: (I have tried: 1.6.3,1.5.2,1.5.0)`

***current package-lock.json depenedency of lambda-local***

```
"lambda-local": {
      "version": "1.5.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/lambda-local/-/lambda-local-1.5.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-wXzmj/DtcR/NuupdrFPW7/jiO2TTacYMA8+EiaOhA2YD5dzv2XsDHIlstUseRhXiiG2vPZcFtiBASRkcEOMGMg==",
      "requires": {
        "aws-sdk": "^2.1.6",
        "chai": "^3.5.0",
        "commander": "^2.6.0",
        "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
        "fs": "^0.0.2",
        "mute": "^2.0.6",
        "winston": "^2.2.0"
      }
    }
```

I am not sure what's actually causing this issue, any help is deeply appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lambda-local is not in your path which is why you are getting that error.

By default if you run the following on windows

```
npm install lambda-local -g
```

Node will install lambda-local to the following directory:

```
C:\Users\[youruser]\AppData\Roaming\npm\
```

Check that lambda-local.cmd is actually in that folder.

By default, `C:\Program Files\nodejs` should be in your path. A command `nodevars.bat` is in the same folder which is run at startup. This updates the path by running `"set "PATH=%APPDATA%\npm;%~dp0;%PATH%"`. I suspect this is not running at startup.

A simple fix is either add nodevars.bat to your startup, or explicitly add the folder C:\Users[youruser]\AppData\Roaming\npm\ to your path, or add the path using the variable name `PATH=%APPDATA%\npm`. i.e press windows button, type in Path, select edit the system environment variables, select environment variables, under system variables edit path, and add that folder to your path.

Restart your command window.